Программа не подчиняется коду
фрагмент кода:
 for h1 in range(0, 34):
    for h2 in range(0, 6):
        if z[h1][h2] = 7:
            k[7] =h1
            print(k[7])
            h1 = 34
            h2 = 6

Я ищу первую 7-ку в файле. По факту z[4][3] = 7.Разве цикл не должен прекратиться при h1=4, h2=3 ?
Я же указываю, что как только находится 7-ка, условия цикла исчерпываются. Но нет, программа не реагирует на z[4][3] = 7, а выдает ответ k[7]=31. Действительно, z[31][6]=7, но почему игнорится
z[4][3] = 7 ? Перепробовал все варианты , чтобы она останавливала поиск , h1 = 33, h2 = 5
h1  = 33  h2 = 6      h1 = 32 h2 = 5 - все-равно первую ( и вторую тоже) 7-ку она игнорит, выдает лишь последнюю в [0,34]. Что бы это означало?алгоритм

шикарное название вопроса!

"Я же указываю, что как только находится 7-ка, условия цикла исчерпываются" — где именно? В этом коде нет ничего похожего.

А разве проверка на равенство - один =? Я, конечно, в Python слаб, но...

Эникейщик: if z[h1][h2] = 7:
h1 = 34
h2 = 6     А ведь именно эти значения h1   и  h2  являются условиями завершения цикла :  for h1 in range(0, 34):
for h2 in range(0, 6):

Нет, это так не работает. Цикл завершается командой break или когда доходит до конца, а изменение h1 и h2 в теле цикла на цикл вообще никак не влияет.

Но ведь должно влиять. Программа следит за значением h1 и h2.  В Pascal  этот прием работает. Кстати, этот фрагмент мне из  Pascal  в Python перевел GPT chat.  А когда я написал, что прога не работает, он извинился и слился. Может, я не в том месте ввожу h1 и h2?  C break я тоже пробовал, безрезультатно.

Нет, в случае range никто за значениями не следит. Цикл начинается и проходит от первого до последнего значения из range. Внутри цикла вы можете делать с переменной все, что заблагорассудится, но в следующей итерации она примет следующее значение. Можете проверить например так: for x in range (10):     print(x)     x = 6     print(x*2)

если с break безрезультатно, то, значит, неправильно использовал

@Harry, да, двойное надо. А ещё выход из цикла вроде так не работает, но я не уверен.

for h1 in range(0, 34):
    for h2 in range(0, 6):
        if z[h1][h2] == 7:
            k[7] =h1
            break
    else: 
        continue
    break

print(k[7])
        

Но лучше обернуть в функцию и прерывать через return - нагляднее и легче запомнить

Помнится, на заре структурного программирования была предложена конструкция, которая элегантно разрешала все подобные ситуации. Оператор цикла можно снабдить меткой, в внутри вложенных циклов использовать оператор break Label;.  Но почему-то это не прижилось...

Это вроде как в питоне не прижилось: PEP 3136 proposes labeled break/continue. Guido rejected it because "code so complicated to require this feature is very rare".

Да, с break работает.
Вот рабочая программа:
for h1 in range(0, 34):
    for h2 in range(0, 6):
        if z[h1][h2] = 7:
            k[7] =h1
            print(k[7])
            break
    if z[h1][h2] = 7:
        break

Моя ошибка была в том, что я использовал break один раз, а надо было дважды.

For...else.. есть

Всё ещё =.. Ну не работает же так...

@eri, кажется, он тут не поможет...  Ему ж наоборот надо break если был break, а не если не было. Но код из ответа выглядит как выход за границу массива, если == поставить как надо. И вообще, какая область видимости у h2?

@Qwertiy else:continue; break

@eri, красиво)))

@Qwertiy костыльненько смотрится конечно, но в спагетти коде почему бы и нет. я такие штуки предпочитаю в функцию обернуть и прерывать по return
